# iphone 5 simulator doesn't load images into UIImage?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, simulator

The following code works as expected in a iPhone 4s simulator running either OS7.1 or OS8.1 and displays a non-zero frame size for the image I am trying to load. The same code in a iPhone 5 or 6 simulator doesn't load the image and displays a zero-size frame for it. What's the difference?

```
UIView *_webBorder;
UIImageView _messagesIcon;

_webBorder = [[UIView alloc] init];
_webBorder.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_webBorder.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_webBorder.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
_webBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.2 blue:0.9 alpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview: _webBorder];

_messagesIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"mIcon"]];
[_webBorder addSubview: _messagesIcon];
NSLog(@"message icon's frame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_messagesIcon.frame ));
```

XCode version 6.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The images were missing from the bundle resources. The mystery is how the iPhone 4 simulator worked without these missing images in the bundle.